# How to search a block of code as a whole

Tags: git

My files has

```
.settings {
}


.field {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

I want to know when

```
.settings {
}
```

was formed.

I know if I want to search **one line of code**, I do `git log -S".settings {"`.

But here I want to search

```
.settings {
}
```

as a whole, I tried

```
git log -S".settings {\r}" confirm.less.css
git log -S".settings {\n}" confirm.less.css
git log -S".settings {\r\n}" confirm.less.css
```

but all retrun nothing.

How do I search **a block of code as a whole** containg new line characters?

Comment: `git log -S` shows you when the specified string was changed in number https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log. So my guess is that the initial commit had the code block with the rule. It's hard to tell why this is happening. Consider just looking at `git log --follow confirm.css` which will give you the revisions of the file.

Comment: @Francisco Instead of searching one line of code, I'm asking how to search  a block of code which, in this case, is `.settings {` and `}` together.

Comment: This isn't really possible, I don't think (where Git tracks changes line-by-line). You could write something to look at diffs and see if the numbers of lines changed is enough to encompass what you're looking for or you could manually look at `git blame` and see when each line was introduced.

Comment: Use `\s*` instead of playing with new line characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a few issues getting this to work properly.

First, I think you need to handle the `{` `}` metacharacters in your RegEx by escaping them, and enable extended matching with `--pickaxe-regex`. I also used a simple `\s*` to greedily match any space including newlines between brackets.

> Here is the resulting command that I came up with
>
> `git log -S".settings \{\s*\}" --pickaxe-regex confirm.less.css`
>
> Which returned the commit containing the first appearance.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
git log -L '/^.settings {/,+1':path/to/it
```

That'll get you the whole history of updates to that range, but the oldest of them will be what you want.